# Ruby Metaprograming and passing Parameters

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing, metaprogramming

I want to define a method in ruby using

```
    define_method
```

within another function. Example code is below.

```
def demo(method_name)
    variable = 5
    define_method "#{method_name}" do
        #stuff
    end
end
```

Inside the newly defined method I want to be able to access the variable:

```
variable=5
```

that was previously defined. For example I want to be able to do :

```
    define_method "#{method_name}" do
        return variable*variable
    end
```

and get variable squared.

I want to be able to:

```
demo("squared")
x = squared # => 25
```

Is there a way I can pass the variable "variable" into the define_method even though it is not in the same scope?

Comment: you are almost done.. What is *stopping* you ?

Comment: Well, I am not sure but block `do
        #stuff
    end` is in the same scope as `variable = 5`. Even I am wrong, that block has access to a mother's scope*. Check this: `a = 42;

l =-> do;
  b = 22;
  l2 = -> do;
    puts a;
  end;
end; l.call.call;` *I am not sure about proper title so I made up that.

Comment: I'm confused. The code you have shown does exactly what you want. So, what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, and what you have works.  What's the problem?

```
[15] pry(main)> def demo(method_name)    
[15] pry(main)*   variable = 5      
[15] pry(main)*   define_method "#{method_name}" do      
[15] pry(main)*     variable * variable        
[15] pry(main)*   end        
[15] pry(main)* end      
=> :demo
[16] pry(main)> demo('squared')
=> :squared
[17] pry(main)> squared
=> 25
```